# "CustomWebpackDevServerSchema" schema is using the keyword "id" which its support is deprecated. Use "$id" for schema ID. Angular ng serve issue

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to run angular application using **ng serve** command. But It is throwing above issue. I have tried updating my angular/node_modules as well. Nothing has worked.

Comment: Whats you OS, Angular Version and Node version? Cause sometimes, the angular version used is not compatible with your current node version. If so, you must update/downgrade your node accorndingly

Comment: Or if you wrote "id" somewhere, try to change it into "$id".